# Existence of antiderivative and analytic(complex)

Tags: complex-analysis

I knew the two facts for $f : D \to \mathbb C$

1. If the function $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$, then$ f$ is continuous on $D$.
2. If the f is analytic on simply connected$ D$, then $f $ has its antiderivative $F(z)$.

Then does this statement holds without the continuity of the $f$ or simply connected $D$?

Statement)
If the f has its antiderivative on $D$, then$ f $is ananyltic on $D$.

P.s.)If the statement is false, what condition I need make it true between both of either continuity or simply connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any region $D$ existence of an anti-derivative for $f$ implies that $f$ is analytic.

This is because derivatives of analytic functions are analytic. (Apply this result to the anti-derivative of $f$).

Comment: Then could we say if the f has its antiderivative on Region D, then f is continuous on D?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang Yes, certainly. In fact it is infinitely differentiable also!